# C IPC - cannot receive message from queue

Tags: c, linux, pointers, ipc

I wrote a simple program in C that uses IPC message queues, but I cannot receive a message when I send it as pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Message {
    long type;
    char content[16];
} Message;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf("Starting...\n");
    key_t key = 1;
    Message* msg = malloc(sizeof(Message));
    int msg_id = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
    printf("ID of the created queue: %d\n", msg_id);
    strcpy(msg->content, "Hello");
    msgsnd(msg_id, msg, 16, 0);
    free(msg);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        int msgid = msgget(key, 0);
        printf("Message queue id: %d\n", msgid);
        Message rcvMsg;
        msgrcv(msgid, &rcvMsg, 16, 0, 0);
        printf("Received: %s\n", rcvMsg.content);

        if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0) != 0) {
            perror("Cannot remove queue from system.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    printf("Stop.\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Output which I got is:

`Starting...
ID of the created queue: 327680
Message queue id: 327680`

And program is waiting. 
But when I send a message as standard variable - not a pointer to structure - the message is delivered.

Working program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf("Starting...\n");
    key_t key = 1;
    Message msg;
    int msg_id = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
    printf("ID of the created queue: %d\n", msg_id);
    strcpy(msg.content, "Hello");
    msgsnd(msg_id, &msg, 16, 0);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        int msgid = msgget(key, 0);
        printf("Message queue id: %d\n", msgid);
        Message rcvMsg;
        msgrcv(msgid, &rcvMsg, 16, 0, 0);
        printf("Received: %s\n", rcvMsg.content);

        if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0) != 0) {
            perror("Cannot remove queue from system.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    printf("Stop.\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

And this program returns expected output:

`Starting...
ID of the created queue: 327680
Message queue id: 327680
Received: Hello
Stop.`

What's going on? What is wrong? How to debug it?

And one more question is what is the best way to create structure variables - pointer or not pointer (btw. what is the name of not pointer variables of structure?)?

`Message msg;` or `Message* msg = malloc(sizeof(Message));`

Comment: "what is the name of not pointer variables of structure" --> "_structure_".

Comment: "what is the best way to create structure variables - pointer or not pointer " should be "what is the best way to create data, as a _structure_ or a _pointer to a structure_?".

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve the code to get no warnings. Read carefully documentation of every system call (cf [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html)) and of standard functions (such as [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)..). Read [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf). **Use the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)** and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not initialize the `type` field of the message. `msgsnd` requires that the type field has a positive integer value.

You should change the code so that it examines the return value of every function with a return value. I found this error by changing `msgsnd(msg_id, msg, 16, 0);` to `int result = msgsnd(msg_id, msg, 16, 0);` and then inserting:

```
if (result == -1)
{
    perror("msgsnd");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This told me that `msgsnd` had an invalid argument, so I reviewed its documentation and found that `type` had to be positive.

You should also examine the return values of `msgrcv`.

For small structures like this, there is no need to `malloc` unless you need the structure to continue to exist after the function that creates it exits. If a function is just going to use a message structure and discard it, declare it locally. If the function is going to return a message structure to its caller, allocate it with `malloc` and return a pointer. (Then the caller is responsible for freeing it later by passing its pointer to `free`.)

Comment: You need to add  msg->type = 1; before msgsnd